# Facing File Import error in Foundry

Tags: solidity, foundry, forge

I am trying to run a forge test. I see the file is in place. But still facing this error.

> Compiler run failed:
> Error (6275): Source "src/oracles/reserve/EthxReserveOracle.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations: "/home/kens/ubntu/foundryprac/x/x-protocol".
> --> test/fork/concrete/SpotOracle.t.sol:12:1:

I am running vscode on wsl ubuntu. Tried cleaning up cache, restarting vscode etc..but of no use.